# Selenium causes Blue screen error in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver, blue-screen-of-death

I wrote a small script to open the browser in selenium but after executing the script after a few seconds my laptop runs into the bluescreen error My code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import *

#chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")

Webdriver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path='E:\Python Projects\Google Meet auto\msedgedriver.exe' )

#driver.implicitly_wait(2)

Webdriver.maximize_window()

Webdriver.get("https://apps.google.com/meet/")
Sign_URL=Webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/header/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[1]/a")

Sign_URL.click()
```

I have windows 10 and chrome built-in Version 86.0.4240.183 (Official Build) (64-bit) Edge Version 86.0.622.63 (Official Build) (64-bit) and drivers are edgedriver_win64 and chromedriver_win32

Comment: Please post the BlueScreen error message.